# is it possible to combine two apis from different .net core solutions under the same swagger portal as different documentation entries?

Tags: c#, .net, swagger

Example:

API1 (solution1) produces swagger/api1/swagger.json

API2 (solution2) produces swagger/api2/swagger.json

The API1 is accessible by url: [www.api1.com](http://www.api1.com)

The API2 is accessible by url: [www.api2.com](http://www.api2.com)

The url [www.apiX.com/swagger_path](http://www.apiX.com/swagger_path) should allow end-user to see API1 and API2 in the dropdownbox "Select a definition".

The entry API1 should switch to the API1 swagger doc with the url [www.api1.com/swagger_path](http://www.api1.com/swagger_path).

The entry API2 should switch to the API2 swagger doc with the url [www.api2.com/swagger_path](http://www.api2.com/swagger_path).

Comment: I guess you would need a third service for just hosting the docs. Maybe you could add mulitple endpoints with absolote paths `options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AbpProjectName API V1");`

Comment: Otherwise take a look at an API Gateway like [Ocelot](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot)